# Save and restore view information with PRISM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm working on an application that has a dockingregion assigned to a docking control. Several modules can register viewmodels to the region through a region adapter and implicit templates are used for visualisation.

I'm now investigating how I can save and restore the toolitems in the dockingcontrol. The control has a feature that allows (de)serialization of the view information and supports lazy loading of the VMs, the views location and docking state is available but as long as no VM is coupled to it it is not visible. The result is that when a VM that maps to a view that was deserialized is added it will be restored in it's previous position. SerializationIds are uses for the mapping.

The problem I'm facing is that this information is available once the shell is initialized and then when the modules initialize they should somehow use this information to add VMs that have deserialized views available.

I have been thinking about several approaches and I end up with this idea. Have some codebehind that handles the deserialization and which calls a command on the ShellVM which then initializes a list with necessary information on the dockingregion's regioncontext. When modules initialize they can check that list and add VMs as they see fit.

Would this be a good approach or are there better techniques to accomplish this?

Many thanks in advance!